# Using Google Maps tile layers: Violation to Google ToS?

Tags: terms-of-service

I've recently bumped into this answer on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32391908/3854787

It shows a way to use the Google Maps tile layers using a direct - probably internal - API.
It is followed by some comments stating that this is a violation of Google's terms of service. I'll transcribe them here, in case they get deleted:

> Its maybe worth mentioning that the Terms of Use from Google forbid any means of tile access other than through the Google Maps API.

and

> [developers.google.com/maps/terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) check out section 10.4e.

Section 10.4e of the ToS states:

> No use of Content with a non-Google map. You must not use the Content in a Maps API Implementation that contains a non-Google map.

To me, this sounds more like: I can't use content available in the Google Maps API (such as geolocation, markers/labels for bussinesses and such) in another maps implementation (Such as, for example, OpenStreetMaps).

Am I wrong? If I'm right, is there any other clause preventing use of the tile layers in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm no expert, I can't know for sure if I'm right about clause **10.4 e**, but I found another clause that makes this question irrelevant in this case:

> **10.1 a:** *No access to APIs or Content except through the Service.* You will not access the Maps API(s) or the Content except through the Service. **For example, you must not access map tiles or imagery through interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces) other than the Maps API(s)**.

*(Emphasis mine)*

This clause is more specific to this use case, and expressly forbids such use of Google Maps content. And luckily for me, the included example emphasized basically answers this question.